# Windows docker, mount a volume and run a script in it

Tags: windows, docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm working with the `servercore` Windows docker image for CI purposes (i.e. building).

I'm fine building it, running it mounting the repo as a volume, launching it and keeping it listening on a specific port and launching exec "mountedFolder/script.bat".

```
docker build . -t build_image
docker run -d -t -p 8585:9090 -v $PATH:c:/repo build_image > id.txt
set /p id=<id.txt
docker exec %id% "build.bat"
```

But is there any way to launch the script (and cd-ing to its folder before launching it), in the run command itself? Something like

```
docker run --rm -v $PATH:c:/repo build_image /PATH/to/BAT/build.bat
```

Comment: You should be able to do exactly what you show in your final example.

Comment: Yes, I was working on it right now. I had to add "WORKDIR C:\\repo\\" on Dockerfile, however